# Finding the longest common subsequence in a variable amount of sets with no repeating characters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sequence

I'm trying to come up with an efficient algorithm that would work in JavaScript for the [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest-common_subsequence_problem). However, there are two main differences between my problem and the one described in the Wikipedia article. The first is that I will have more than two sets of characters. The second is that characters will never repeat in a set. This means that the length of each set will be at most about 50 characters (i.e. the printable ASCII chars).

For example, the sets may contain:

```
A = ZBANICOT
B = ACNTBZIO
C = ANICOTZB
D = ZIANCOTB
```

... and it should output `ACO`, `ACT`, `ANO`, and `ANT`, since these are the longest subsequences in all 4 sets (as far as I can tell from manually examining these sets).

Since none of the letters repeat, is there a more efficient algorithm I should consider rather than the one described in the Wikipedia article? If not, is there anywhere that describes how to convert the algorithm to having N sets instead of 2?

Comment: @Senseful Misunderstood your question, so I have deleted that answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: thanks, I updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how efficient an adaption of the normal LCS algorithm would be, so this may be inefficient, but since there aren't many eligible letters, it's not too horrible.

Make a successor matrix. For each string `s`, for each pair of letters `(s[i],s[j])` with `i < j`, increment `matrix[s[i]][s[j]]`. A pair of letters can only be part of a longest common subsequence if `matrix[a][b] = n = number of strings`. Build a directed graph from the letters participating in such a pair, with an edge from `a` to `b` iff  `matrix[a][b] = n`. Find a longest path in that graph.

Comment: +1: That is the solution. Could have saved myself a great deal of time by reading this before writing my long winded answer

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm now looking for a solution which finds several of the longest paths and I'm running into a few problems. If you think you could help, could you please take a look at [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691834/eliminating-extraneous-edges-in-directed-acyclic-graph-while-trying-to-find-long)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called [multiple sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment). The algorithm 'could' be rewritten to be n-dimensional, but that would increase the space complexity to `Length ^ Dimensions`.

> Since none of the letters repeat, is there a more efficient algorithm I should consider rather than the one described in the Wikipedia article?

Perhaps. First create a mapping (a,b) such that a < b. For example the mappings for the first three characters of each sets is as follows

```
--- Mapping for character[0]
Z - B    A - C    A - N    Z - I
    A        N        I        A
    N        I        C        N
    I        B        O        C
    C        Z        T        O
    O        I        Z        T
    T        O        B        B

--- Mapping for character[1]
B - A    C - N    N - I    I - A
    N        I        C        N
    I        B        O        C
    C        Z        T        O
    O        I        Z        T
    T        O        B        B

--- Mapping for character[2]
A - N    N - I    N - C    I - N
    I        B        O        C
    C        Z        T        O
    O        I        Z        T
    T        O        B        B
```

Then retain only mappings that are common on all sets. Here's an example of following this process, traversing Set[A] (`ZBANICOT`), which will give us a set of relations that are common to all sets.

So with the letter `Z` you will observe that in Set[C], the only character that follows `Z` is `B`, so you can eliminate just about every mapping from `Z` that is not to B. But to cut a long story short, every mapping for `Z` is removed. Note, only mappings from Z are removed, not mappings to `Z`.

Also note that since Set[D] ends with `B`, we can safely eliminate all mappings from `B`. By following the process one can observe that `A` maps to `N`, `C`, `O` and `T`. Next is N, which maps to `T` and `O`.

`I` maps to `O` (honestly, "I/O") while `C` maps to `O` and `T` (how cute). And funnily enough `O` maps to nothing!!! How befitting.

Finally there is one more character, and `T` maps to nothing too (since `ZBANICOT` ends with `T`).

In the end you are left with the following mappings:

```
A - C    C - O    I - O    N - O
    N        T                 T
    O
    T
```

Now all you have to do is start from each of the keys (`A`, `C`, `I` and `N`) and search for the longest sequence without any repeating nodes (characters in this case).

Here are all of the common subsequences (all using the simple algorithm):

```
ACO
ACT
ANO
ANT
AO
AT
CO
CT
IO
NT
NO
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm now looking for a solution which doesn't contain the `AO` and `AT` results, though. I just asked a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691834/eliminating-extraneous-edges-in-directed-acyclic-graph-while-trying-to-find-long) about this.

Comment: I'll reply in [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691834/eliminating-extraneous-edges-in-directed-acyclic-graph-while-trying-to-find-long)

Answer (score 0):

What if I stored character mapping for each set of characters and then incremented this count each time...

For the 1st set (`ZBANICOT`), this would create the following character pairs (28 of them):

```
ZB, ZA, ZN, ZI, ZC, ZO, ZT
    BA, BN, BI, BC, BO, BT
        AN, AI, AC, AO, AT
            NI, NC, NO, NT
                IC, IO, IT
                    CO, CT
                        OT
```

For the 2nd set (`ACNTBZIO`), I would have 28 pairs again:

```
AC, AN, AT, AB, AZ, AI, AO
    CN, CT, CB, CZ, CI, CO
        NT, NB, NZ, NI, NO
            TB, TZ, TI, TO
                BZ, BI, BO
                    ZI, ZO
                        IO
```

For the last 2 sets, I would have:

```
AN, AI, AC, AO, AT, AZ, AB
    NI, NC, NO, NT, NZ, NB
        IC, IO, IT, IZ, IB
            CO, CT, CZ, CB
                OT, OZ, OB
                    TZ, TB
                        ZB

ZI, ZA, ZN, ZC, ZO, ZT, ZB
    IA, IN, IC, IO, IT, IB
        AN, AC, AO, AT, AB
            NC, NO, NT, NB
                CO, CT, CB
                    OT, OB
                        TB
```

(So to figure out the iteration count so far, let `N` equal the number of sets, and `M` be the number of characters in each set, we have `N*(M)((M-1)/2)` or `4*28=112` in this example)

Next, I would count the number of times each pair exists. For example,

```
PairCounts["ZB"] == 3
PairCounts["ZA"] == 2
// ...
PairCounts["AO"] == 4
PairCounts["AT"] == 4
// ...
PairCounts["AN"] == 4
PairCounts["AC"] == 4
PairCounts["CT"] == 4
PairCounts["NO"] == 4
PairCounts["NT"] == 4
```

Then, since we have 4 pairs, I would discard all pairs which don't have a count of 4. And then I would try concatting each pair in order to form the longest string possible.

Comment: You're on the right track, see my post - and I only spotted that because of your query on there being a more efficient algorithm *because* they are unique sets.